# jQuery appendTo breaks links on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have recreated the material design ripple effect in jQuery, and it works great in IE11 and Chrome 46, but on Firefox 39, if i apply the effect to links, it prevents the redirection. I have managed to find out that the function that breaks my code is the `jQuery.appendTo()` function.

Fiddle:
http://codepen.io/grekomp/pen/pjpzKQ

As you can see, when you click on the link in Chrome it works, but Firefox only runs the js and ignores the link.

Any idea how to fix it? I would like to use some cross-browser compatible solution.

Comment: FF 39 is not the latest version. Did you check Bug reports for this version?

Comment: No, but I just updated to firefox 40 and the issue persists

Comment: Maybe use `$(this)` versus `this` in your code.

Comment: Tested using `$(this)` in FF and it works as expected. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwpGNw

Comment: Updated the pen, still not working for me

Comment: Using FF 41 I am unable to replicate the issue when using `$(this)`.

Comment: Perhaps it was fixed in Firefox 41, but it's still not a satisfactory answer, I have to support current versions of Firefox too.

Comment: What is expected behavior? Use `target="_blank"` for new tab

Comment: @Grekomp I understand completely, yet I only have FF41 to test with and it's working. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Sure, give me a second. Tested on Firefox 41 and it's not working for me...

Comment: This is helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: @Twisty I know that I shoud have used `$(this)` but it was just an example. Uploaded my full code now, take a look.

Comment: @Grekomp is there a reason why you're using mousedown?

Comment: @Daemedeor I want the ripple effect to appear when the user presses the mouse button, not on release ( which is what click does )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't add the `$overlay` div then the link works as expected, and you get most of the visual affect.  I'm not sure why, but adding that div breaks the link - and only on Firefox.

I suggest you open a bug for the Firefox devs, maybe they can help you with a better workaround.

**Edit:**
*Found a solution!*

Add `pointer-events: none;`  css to both your `.ripple-effect` and `.ripple-overlay` divs.

Comment: I might do so, for the sake of developement, but my problem was already solved, by adding `pointer-events: none` to the css of .ripple-effect and .ripple-overlay

Comment: damn, I found the same solution just as you wrote the comment

Comment: Thanks for trying! I have marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're using the mousedown event and not the click event... so FF is not firing both events (unlike chrome and IE) and only firing the mousedown event so your solution (tested on FF v31):

```
$('.ripple').on('mousedown', rippleEffect );
```

Edit: since mousedown has to work, its a bug in FF maybe that only click or mousedown has to fire at once. so its a little inelegant but replicates the solution that you're asking for...

Add this to the end of your mousedown handler

```
 this.click();
```

or even better, from SO mentioned on another answer ([Mousedown and Click conflict on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352128/mousedown-and-click-conflict-on-firefox)) no race events will happen with this one:

a.ripple { 
      pointer-events: none;
  }

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue, as I want the function to work on mousedown, to give instant visual feedback to the user.

Comment: personally though, i don't know why even bother with a ripple because target="_blank" runs so fast and makes it the active tab that the user would barely even be able to see the actual animation

Comment: Normal links don't work on codepen, so I added `target="_blank"` to illustrate the issue

Comment: fair enough, I don't use codepen a whole lot for js stuff

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem, as i do not want to trigger a click event on mousedown. It changes the default link behavior

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `this` to `$(this)` to apply JQuery to the object:

```
$("a").on("mousedown", function() {
    var p = $(this);
    var div = $('<div/>');
    div.text("Hello");
    div.appendTo(p);
});

$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
});
```

Tested in FF 41 on Windows. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwpGNw

In your new code, I found:

```
$overlay.addClass('ripple-overlay')
    .css({
    background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
})
    .appendTo($(this));;
```

Removing the extra semicolon will not make much a different, yet that was hit on JSHint. I even moved the same code to a jsfiddle to test too: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/p4fvjvtf/ I forked your pen with the minor change, and still works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwpwOE

Maybe I am missing what is not working.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, it looks like adding `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS for the created `DIV` resolved the issue.

Comment: Still not working for me, besides, the pen is just an example, my full code doesn't look exactly the same

Comment: The pen is working for me. Are you sure you want to use `appendTo()` and not `appendAfter()`? You want  to add the `DIV` inside your `A`?

Comment: Works for me in FF, I get the ripple affect clicking any place in the green box. I did find a few things that need to be cleaned up. Will edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: The ripple effect works on all tested browsers, but the green box is a link and it should open google in a new tab. On Firefox this doesn't happen

Comment: I see now. And found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352128/mousedown-and-click-conflict-on-firefox ?